# ¿Es buena práctica combinar el estandar MVVM con programación en capas?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mvc, wpf, mvvm

Dado que no he encontrado mayores referencias a este tema ni una guía de buenas prácticas no he podido formar un criterio.

Estoy recién entrando al mundo MVVM con WPF y veo que existen varias referencias en donde se menciona que dentro de un proyecto MVVM deben existir las tres carpetas estándar Model, View y ViewModel, sin embargo quería saber si es buena práctica combinar ese estándar con la forma de programación en capas, es decir, crear un proyecto para acceso a datos, otro para lógica de negocio y en un tercero tener MVVM con sus respectivas carpetas.

Mi pregunta es, ¿es buena práctica combinar el estandar MVVM con programación en capas?

El proyecto que estoy armando va a estar todo en C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así como yo lo veo, MVVM separa VISTA y CÓDIGO, siendo el código el que se divide en Model y ViewModel, ahora bien, con eso claro, los Models -que vendrían siendo algo así como las clases tipicas, persona, boleta, etc- deben ser actualizadas desde el ViewModel y a su vez el ViewModel debe leer los cambios en el Model por lo que deduzco que el acceso a datos va en el ViewModel, ahora aquí es donde yo llego a la misma pregunta, es bueno poner acceso por capas? y mi respuesta es Absolutamente SI.

¿Porqué? Porque ayuda a ordenar aún más el código, yo llevo 2 años como desarrollador C# y en WPF siempre uso MVVM mezclado con capas, PERO cuando se trata de los Models también aplico el principio de que se autogestionen, por ejemplo al actualizar un dato de una persona en la BD, lo lógico para mi sería llamarlo como Persona.Update() o algo así;

Luego centralizo los controladores y creo un conector para cada tipo de conexión que el software realize.. así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Naturalmente no soy dueño de la verdad y debe haber quien tenga un enfoque más acertado, pero al menos por mi parte creo que trabajar así es una muy buena manera de mantener ordenado cada módulo, MVVM es muy general pero flexible a la vez y no hay nada de malo en tomar lo mejor de cada patrón y adaptarlo a lo que tu requieras, recuerda que la tecnología se hace para adaptarse a ti y no al revés.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Leodev por la excelente explicación y el nivel de detalle. El gráfico aclara mucho los conceptos.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de como quieras estructurar tu proyecto. Recuerda que los patrones de diseño son solo eso, son una guía pero depende de ti y de las necesidades del proyecto el que las implementes de una u otra forma.

Puedes utilizar capas, incluso puede que mvc/mvvm/mvp sean solo la capa de presentación y tengas aparte tu capa de negocios y luego la de datos, o puedes implementar la capa de negocios en el modelo.

Yo lo que hago es que dependiendo de la complejidad del proyecto, separo o no la lógica de negocios, también si se va a reusar o no la lógica de negocio la separo y dejo el modelo mas limpio y con menos carga.